# Angular 5 reactive form valueChanges does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a form inside a service:

```
    this.settingsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        names: this.formBuilder.array([]),
        globalIDs: this.formBuilder.array([]),
        topics: this.formBuilder.array([]),
        emails: this.formBuilder.array([]),
        description: ''
    });
```

and a getter for convenience-

```
get description(): FormControl{
    return this.settingsForm.get('description') as FormControl;
}
```

in some directive I am injecting the service and have a input that attached to this control. html-

```
<textarea matInput
          [formControl]="settingsDataService.description">
</textarea>
```

In the directive I have a listener:

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.listenToSearchInput();
    }

listenToSearchInput() {
    this.settingsDataService.description.valueChanges.pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),takeUntil(this.descriptionDestroy))
        .subscribe(value => {
          //DO SOMETHING
        });
}
```

but when I am typing in the textarea, my subscriber does not get called.

**Maybe it is relevenat- but after listenToSearchInput() is called, in the service after I get an answer from the server I am filling description by-**

```
this.settingsForm.patchValue({description:description});
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: where is the descriptionDestroy get defined

Comment: What is `descriptionDestroy` in your code? `takeUntil` takes timer as the parameter

Comment: No, `takeUntil` takes any observable as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer- in the function that gets data from the server, I create a new seetingsForm to clean the previous data..

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to call the function in `onChanges` life cycle hook of your directive.

```
onChanges(): void {
   this.settingsDataService.description.valueChanges.pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),takeUntil(this.descriptionDestroy))
        .subscribe(value => {
          //DO SOMETHING
        });
}
```

Comment: but I don't have any input in my component, so way calling this life cycle? I added another information in the question, thanks!

Comment: I just mean to say you need to call your `listenToSearchInput` functionality in `onChanges` not in OnInit

Comment: So where you expecting changes in formControl?

Comment: I am just listening to my formControl. I have it because I injected the service

Comment: ok, I found the answer- in the function that gets data from the server, I create a new seetingsForm....